# Using an Instance Variable in more than one method

Tags: cocoa-touch

How would I save an Instance so that I could use it in another method?
This is the code I have:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint     touchedStart;

    // find position of the touch
    touchedStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint     touchedEnd;

    // find position of the touch
    touchedEnd = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

}
```

I want to be able to use the `touchedStart` variable in the `touchesEnded` method. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a member variable in the class itself - then the other method will be able to access it.

Comment: @Joshua - It's a variable that is a member of the class (also called an instance variable) as opposed to a "local variable" which is what you have now.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean know I just got a bit confused. Thanks!